# In Excel SUM return 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet and when I use a SUM formula in a cell and then I select columns, it returns `0`.

[image]

[image]

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Check for circular references. If the cell with the formula is in the range that SUM() refers to, you will get a 0 as a result.

Comment: No, the range is normal, this doesn't work either @teylyn

Comment: Well, it's hard to troubleshoot data type problems and formula errors from a screenshot. Share the workbook on an ad-free service like OneDrive or DropBox and then post a link, so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Also, post the exact formula you are using and post the cell address of the cell that has the formula.